# Conversion from List<Map<K,V>> to List<V> (Get all the unique values from a List of Maps)

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have `List<Map<String, Object >>` like:

```
[
   {"code":last_name},
   {"code":last_date}, 
   {"code":task_id}
]
```

Now I Want to convert this in List like this:

```
 [last_name, last_date, task_id]
```

I have used this code for converting this

```
List<Object> allCodeKeeper = new ArrayList<Object>();
for(Map<String,Object> map : list){
    if(!allCodeKeeper.contains(map.get("code"))){
        allCodeKeeper.add(map.get("code"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[last_name, last_date, task_id]
```

But I want this conversion using Lambda expression.

Comment: "[
       {code=last_name},
       {code=last_date}, 
       {code=task_id}
   ]".. How is this a map? is `code` the key in the `Map`?

Comment: yes code is the key

Comment: Your title is wrong; you are “converting” to a `List<V>`, not `List<K>`

Comment: ya thanks for reminding me i have updated it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
List<Object> allCodeKeeper = list.stream().map(o -> o.get("code"))
                .distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Sample run**

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String,Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("code", "last_name");
    Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("code", "last_date");
    map2.put("code","last_name");//adding a duplicate on purpose
    Map<String,Object> map3 = new HashMap<>();
    map3.put("code", "task_id");
    list.add(map1);
    list.add(map2);
    list.add(map3);
    List<Object> allCodeKeeper = list.stream().map(o -> o.get("code"))
            .distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(allCodeKeeper);
```

That said, you are better off using a `Set` rather than using a `List` for your result since you want to eliminate the duplicate values. :

```
Set<Object> uniqueCodeKeeper = list.stream().map(o -> o.get("code"))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: it is not for unique values . i am not checking uniqueness.but it is good for checking the unique values.but here i do not need unique check @CKing

Comment: If you don't need unique values, why does your question have this line  `if(!allCodeKeeper.contains(map.get("code"))){` You said you wanted to convert the code into lambda. The code you show includes uniqueness check.

Answer (score 1):

If i get it right , this looks like solving your query.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

/*Prepare Data*/
    List<Map<String , Object>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String , Object>>();

    Map<String , Object> mapOfStringToObject1 = new HashMap<String , Object>();

    mapOfStringToObject1.put("code", "last_name");

    Map<String , Object> mapOfStringToObject2 = new HashMap<String , Object>();

    mapOfStringToObject2.put("code", "last_date");

    Map<String , Object> mapOfStringToObject3 = new HashMap<String , Object>();
    mapOfStringToObject3.put("code", "task_id");

    listOfMaps.add(mapOfStringToObject1);
    listOfMaps.add(mapOfStringToObject2);
    listOfMaps.add(mapOfStringToObject3);

/*And the lambda , missed the distinct !*/


    List<Object> allCodeKeeper = listOfMaps.stream().map(mapOfString -> mapOfString.values()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

    allCodeKeeper.forEach(System.out::println);


}
```

Comment: Not the downvoter but you seem to have missed the part that the OP does not want any duplicates in the final result `List`.

Comment: Thanks King , i guess i should have added a distinct too. Thanks for posting a comment !

Comment: you have tried but your output is not expecting as i wanted but close enough to get my Result liitle bit chnage your code give the desired result <code>List<Object> allCodeKeeper = listOfMaps.stream().map(mapOfString -> mapOfString.get("code")).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());</code>

Comment: your output is  [[last_name], [last_date], [task_id]] instead of [last_name, last_date, task_id]

Comment: change -: mapOfString -> mapOfString.values() into  mapOfString -> mapOfString.get("code") i have upvoted for your effort not for accepted answer

Comment: Good approach, but you have to use `.flatMap` rather than `.map` for the OP’s intended result. Here, it backfires to have `Object` as list element type, which hides the semantic differences.

Answer (score 1):

Otherway to do is

```
Set<Object> output= list.stream()  //  Stream<Map<String, Object>>
    .map(Map::values)              // Stream<List<Object>>
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)   // Stream<Object>
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());  //Set<Object>
```